# What complications arise when designing a USB device sharing switch?

Tags: usb, switches

I wish to design and build a USB switch capable of transferring one USB keyboard between one of two computers.   I wish to automate the process of unplugging the device from host A and plugging it into host B and vice versa.

What are the complications that arise when trying to do so, and what different solutions are there on an analog (i.e. just mechanically switch all 4 or 8 cables from one side to the other) or digital level?

---

If we choose an analog design, it should be straightforward to completely interrupt the connection between the device host A and establish a connection between the device and host B. I understand that this necessitates USB re-enumeration and so on, but from an outside perspective, there is no obvious reason why this should not work as well as unplugging and replugging.
I am aware that commercial solutions to this requirement exist.

---

Most commercially available devices on the other hand seem to opt for a digital switching solution instead. What are the benefits of doing so, and what additional drawbacks are there (the possibility of unintentionally feeding voltage to upstream ports comes to mind)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because price and quality of consumer products is not an engineering problem, but the result of market forces.

Comment: Well, in that case the answer to my question would be _nothing, it's just the market making it appear more complicated/expensive than it is_? That would be a fair answer to my question, I'm genuinely asking about any complications that I may be overlooking, not trying to deride commercial products.

Comment: A problem with switching a USB devices between two hosts is that USB assumed from its inception that it would be humans plugging it in. I have experienced this first hand when employed to debug such a switch, that sometimes failed. It turned out to be that enumeration is not reliable unless there's a reasonable delay (hundreds of ms) between disconnecting from one and connecting to the other, something a mechanical switch does not provide. It needn't have been the case, it just seems to be baked into the protocol. That's for XP and win7 anyway, may be different for other operating systems.

Comment: ... so use two switches, one to connect each one, perhaps wired so that you can't connect the two hosts accidentally. Then you can easily add the required delay manually.

Comment: @Neil_UK That seems like a great answer to my question (--> repost it as an answer?) and something that's not obvious from the outside. Do you have any idea what the underlying mechanism is, or did you just observe this "experimentally"?

Comment: If the switching were fast enough that supply capacitors in the keyboard never discharged, it might not realize it had been re-plugged.  Or maybe they cheat and try to use diodes rather than a switch on the power.  If you were going to do this right, you should break the data lines, cut power, wait, connect new power and then connect the data lines just after.  If it's for personal use and you will only ever use it with a keyboard or mouse, you could play a bit loose with the wiring, use relays, etc.  But no if you wanted to put a hub there that's probably going to be USB-HS upstream.

Comment: you can buy a KVM switch ... it should not require ennumeration when switching

Comment: @jsotola - that would only be the case if the switch functions as a proxy, ie, hosts the keyboard itself and pretends to be two always connected keyboards to the hosting computers, only one of which happens to send keystrokes when the real one is used.  Certainly possible, and allows hotkey switching, but unclear its what is on the market and easy to imagine the firmware turning out just slightly wrong yielding complaints.  In that realm there are also software solutions which forward keystrokes over a network to a software key injector on each host, of course they don't work in early bootup.

Comment: No answer, as it was never persued to a solution. I had some relay boxes that 'worked', and some that failed 'sometimes'. The key observation was when their failure statistics changed when moving between XP and win7 OS's. Timing was the obvious culprit as, in addition, everything worked manually. So we stopped trying to switch instantly, and moved on to more important things without a backward glance. But it's worth bearing in mind if you try to repeat that setup. It may be all different with later OS's?

Comment: Chris Stratton has all the answer - you need to provide various delays when making the switch. And if you fail to provide 480 Mbps signal quality with poorly designed PCB, your HS flash drives either won't work at all or might be corrupted.

Comment: I disagree with the notion that this question is off-topic for this site. I'll rewrite the question to shift the focus off of existing commercial products and onto the complications that arise when designing such a switch, which is what I was trying to get at. This has already been addressed by several people whose comments I would consider good answers if they were posted as answers (thanks to all of you!).

Comment: Based on all comments and on reopen votes and on OP's editing of question I again edited the post to further direct it towards a specific design and build question (which the op always indicated it was) and reopened it. Comments welcome.

Comment: Thank you for the reconsideration, and I'm sorry that the original phrasing was somewhat rant-y, I was frustrated about the commercial solutions when I wrote it. As stated above, I believe the comments from other users have pointed out some significant and non-obvious points (e.g. regarding re-enumeration time, residual currents/charge) that answer my question and which have helped me understand the problem.

Comment: I didn't "mind" your phrasing. Your intentions fitted the site ethos but some felt the phrasing made it not so. Many questions are genuinely site-appropriate but wording made it less obvious I was trying to make the intentions clear so all would be happy. (All are never happy, but we can try :-) ).